# Laravel - count the total number of records in "threaded" records

Tags: php, multithreading, laravel

Consider a forum which can have many sub-forums which can have more sub-forums.

My `forums` table is like this:

`id`, `parent_id`, `name`, `is_category`

A forum category (`is_category`) cannot have threads in them. However, it can have The `parent_id` is the `id` in the `forums` table; it's a way I can put a sub-forum in a forum. In short, a forum can have many sub-forums which can have many more sub-forums which can have more sub-forums and so on...

Demo Records:

```
| id | parent_id | name              | is_category |
|----|-----------|-------------------|-------------|
| 1  | 0         | Suggestions       | 1           |
| 2  | 1         | site suggestions  | 0           |
| 3  | 1         | forum suggestions | 0           |
| 4  | 2         | bugs              | 0           |
```

My view:

```
@if ($forum->hasSubforum())
    @foreach ($forum->subforums as $subforum)
        {{ $subforum->name }}

        <h1>subforums</h1>
        @if ($forum->hasSubforum())
        @foreach ($subforum->subforums as $child)
            {{ $subforum->name }}
        @endforeach
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endif
```

What I have tried:

```
$threads = 0;
while(!$forum->subforums->isEmpty()) {
    $threads += $forum->threads->count();
    while(!$forum->subforums->isEmpty()) {
        $threads += $forum->threads->count();
    }
}
```

This doesn't even work... :(

**TL;DR** As you can see, I display the subforms to a user. Butwhat if I want to display how many posts a subforum has? Please do note that a subforum can have more subforums which can then have many threads. I cannot simply do `$subforum->threads->count()` as that would only count the threads that each subforum has. I also want to count the number of threads all children of the subforum have.

Comment: [Laravel recursive query answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22014903/laravel-query-builder-for-recursive-results-e-g-id-parent-id).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with recursion.

```
function countThreads($forum) {
    $count = $forum->threads->count();
    if ($forum->hasSubforum()) { {
        foreach ($forum->subforums as $subforum) {
            $count += countThreads($subforum);
        }
    }
    return $count;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The `$count = 0` at the top is always making the count 0 when it does recursion...

Comment: If you run the function with deepest subforum as argument do you get correct count?

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my other comment. No, it doesn't get the correct count.

Comment: Then the problem is somewhere else, because with deepest subforum the recursion does not execute and it should give you the same count as calling $deepestSubforum->threads->count() directly.

Comment: Sorry, I checked again and it does get the current count. I checked a forum which was not the deepest. So yes, it does get the current count.

Comment: Sometimes I suprise myself with the wtf code. I've updated the answer.